# Get ocamlmerlin autocomplete in vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete, ocaml, merlin

I'm trying to get autocompletion for OCaml. I like using Vim and I found this plugin:

https://github.com/the-lambda-church/merlin

I installed it using OPAM and added the required lines to load it to my .vimrc

I made sure that OPAM bin folder (which contains ocamlmerlin) is in my .profile file and 
checked that I can access it from the terminal and for vim I printed the PATH variable using "Ctrl-r =$PATH" and it shows that it contains OPAM bin folder.

It still doesn't work, I have no clue what else to do to make it work. I get syntax highlighting but that exists without merlin anyway. I want autocompletion to work.

If I press Ctrl-N to show completion suggestion I get "normal" vim completion which is basically just a list of words that are mentioned in the document.

Checking the startup log file, I can see that Vim did indeed load merlin:

```
chdir(/home/incraved/.opam/system/share/ocamlmerlin/vim/plugin)
fchdir() to previous dir
sourcing "/home/incraved/.opam/system/share/ocamlmerlin/vim/plugin/merlin.vim"
finished sourcing /home/incraved/.opam/system/share/ocamlmerlin/vim/plugin/merlin.vim
Searching for "/home/incraved/.opam/system/share/ocamlmerlin/vimbufsync/plugin/**/*.vim"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl-N is the default completion; its sources are configured by the `'complete'` option, but cannot include custom sources.

The Merlin plugin uses **Omni completion**, which is triggered with Ctrl-X Ctrl-O; see `:help compl-omni`.

Comment: It says omnifunc is not defined?

Comment: Thanks I found it !! I needed to enable it first:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Omni_completion